# How to tell css_styled_content to properly resize images

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I think I am experiencing this ages-old behaviour in a TYPO3 6.1 site
http://forge.typo3.org/issues/15522

As soon as there is more than one image in a textpic field, this TypoScript

```
tt_content.image.20.maxWInText = 300
```

will produce very small images - their size is the given rendering size divided by number of images.

So with three images in a textpic element, this will give me three 100px wide images.

How can this be set to work normally (value 300 applied to each image?)

EDIT: I'm posting the full config I've been using:

```
imgWidth=CASE
imgWidth{
    key.field = header_layout
    default=TEXT
    default.value=1000
    1=TEXT
    1.value=1000
    2=TEXT
    2.value=500
    3=TEXT
    3.value=300
    4=TEXT
    4.value=500
    5=TEXT
    5.value=300
    6=TEXT
    6.value=500
    7=TEXT
    7.value=300
    8=TEXT
    8.value=0
    9=TEXT
    9.value=0
    10=TEXT
    10.value=150
    10=TEXT
    10.value=1000
}   

tt_content.image.20.maxWInText.cObject < imgWidth
tt_content.image.20.maxW.cObject < imgWidth
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting is supposed to affect the width occupied by all images in a column. Therefore it must effect all images.

You should take a look at

```
tt_content.image.20.maxW
```

Comment: Thanks - I erroneously thought `maxWInText` was for textpic elements. Now I've tried with only `tt_content.image.20.maxW = 300` - and ran into another issue: the created image has only half that width, minus 5px. So only 145px, if passing 300px. I remember that back in the days I had to define image widths double to get them rendered as supposed. But I thought that was gone. Is there an explanation?

Comment: Maybe this is the default such that you always have a least half of a text column. Well, if the double width works for you, just use it as is.

Comment: Unfortunately, this behaviour comes in play only when there's more than one image in a CE. So in most cases (where there's only one image), I would get double sized images. Is there a way to test for the number of images in TS?

Comment: Yes you can, but this logic is not pure TS, but a special render method that is called inside of CSC.

Comment: Sorry Philipp, I saw your answer just now. OMG, I don't think I want to hack CSC. Is this related to http://forge.typo3.org/issues/45086 ? If so, could it be that this was fixed for 6.2 only, not for lower 6.x? I'm still learning how to read these review pages

Comment: Yes, that is what the commit message states. It was merged in Jan, therefore it is included in 6.2.